# Hide user folders in Windows Explorer on Windows 11 v22H2

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-11

After updating to 22H2 windows started showing folders like Documents, Downloads, Videos, Music, Pictures, etc on windows explorer tree view. I could disable "Show all folders" but I really only want to hide these folders. I tried the well known methods to hide them from "This PC" but that didn't work. Any ideas?

[image: Image showing Windows Explorer with user folders visible]

Comment: 22H2 removed Quick Access and replaced it with HOME.  I think this is what you are seeing.  You should be able to remove shortcuts in the main HOME screen. I do not bother. It is all my own stuff so I just adapted to the new method.

Comment: It's actually under desktop as you can see on the right pane. My "Home" have only the shortcuts I want.

Comment: @bortao 1)can you add further details to your question. As it currently is & Windows default is for Desktop, Documents, etc. to be under Quick Access or Home in the left side of File Explorer as 'pinned' items. 2)Are you 100% sure your Desktop doesn't have those folders as well (Videos, Pictures, etc.)? 3)Can you explain HOW you access this 'Desktop' view in File Explorer? 4)Can you right-click Desktop, Properties, & upload that picture?

Comment: FYI there are two views of 'Desktop' in File Explorer: 1)default pinned Desktop. 2)Click Home or Quick Access then hit Up arrow; alternatively you can click left-most arrow in the path bar then go to Desktop. Microsoft MAY have designed this to show these common user folders.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/how-to-get-to-the-desktop-documents-and-pictures-folders-in-file-explorer-3370f06b-0f8d-4b25-be9a-3ee54f381e3d

Comment: 1) They are not pinned under Home or This PC, they are directly under Desktop on the tree view. They also show on the right side. They don't show on my desktop, only on Explorer. This happened recently when I upgraded windows. 2) 100% 3) Folder options -> View -> Navigation Pane -> Show all folders 4) This take me to "Personalization" on control panel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to remove the following folders under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace_36354489`

```
1CF1260C-4DD0-4ebb-811F-33C572699FDE = My Music
374DE290-123F-4565-9164-39C4925E467B = Downloads
3ADD1653-EB32-4cb0-BBD7-DFA0ABB5ACCA = My Pictures
A0953C92-50DC-43bf-BE83-3742FED03C9C = My Videos
A8CDFF1C-4878-43be-B5FD-F8091C1C60D0 = Documents
B4BFCC3A-DB2C-424C-B029-7FE99A87C641 = Desktop
```

Comment: There are no such entries in Win11 registry at this location. I wanted to remove user folders from the desktop menu (those user folders don't show on desktop, but they do show in the 'Desktop' menu (also sometimes called 'Toolbar') that I've added on my windows taskbar.

Answer (score 1):

In my Window 11 22H2 virtual machine, if I right-click on these folders
and select "Unpin from Quick access", the folder is removed from the list.

See also the article
[Add or Remove Folders under This PC in File Explorer in Windows 11](https://www.elevenforum.com/t/add-or-remove-folders-under-this-pc-in-file-explorer-in-windows-11.7122/),
where registry updates are described for removing (and adding back)
these specific entries that are displayed under "This PC".

Comment: Sorry, they are not pinned. Also I mention in my question exactly "I tried the well known methods to hide them from "This PC" but that didn't work"

Comment: They are supposed to be pinned under This PC, not under Desktop. (1) What right-click options do you have on these entries? A screenshot will be best. (2) Does it change when booting in Safe mode?

Comment: (3) Check if [these registry items](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/my-pictures-music-videos-namespace-extensions-for-windows-explorer-folder-pane/) were added to your registry under the keys `[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{88250a20-f8f7-4cb9-a5e7-9e8e7746764X}]`, where X is 0,1,2 (and maybe more). (4) In Explorer Options, View tab, ensure Hidden files and folders are shown, and see if these folders are now shown on the desktop.

Comment: 1) Same items of any folder 2) Same thing 3) Keys are absent (The folders only appeared after 22H2) 4) Always had hidden files shown. Folders are absent from desktop.

Comment: Think I found it... just out of luck. Found these items and removed them, and the folders were gone immediately: All under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace_36354489 - {1CF1260C-4DD0-4ebb-811F-33C572699FDE} CLSID_ThisPCMyMusicRegFolder {374DE290-123F-4565-9164-39C4925E467B} CLSID_ThisPCDownloadsRegFolder {3ADD1653-EB32-4cb0-BBD7-DFA0ABB5ACCA} CLSID_ThisPCMyPicturesRegFolder {A0953C92-50DC-43bf-BE83-3742FED03C9C} CLSID_ThisPCMyVideosRegFolder {A8CDFF1C-4878-43be-B5FD-F8091C1C60D0} CLSID_ThisPCDocumentsRegFolder

Answer (score 1):

You can hide them in "File Explorer" properties.\

Head to "View" -> "Options" -> "Change folder and searching options", then you'll find  this:

[image: [Click to view image]]

Comment: This is very far from what I want